# Flowtype error with react: This type is incompatible with props of JSX Intrinsic

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

```
React.createElement(FilterLink, { filter: 'SHOW_ALL', children: React.createElement(
    'span',
    null, // flow error : null This type is incompatible with props of JSX Intrinsic: `span`
    'All'
  ) }),
```

Can someone explain what this error means ?

Answer (score 1):

Got answer on IRC:

```
React.createElement(FilterLink, { filter: 'SHOW_ALL', children: React.createElement(
    'span',
    {}, // no more error
    'All'
  ) }),
```